# How to establish M2M communication with gammu?

Tags: sms, gsm, modem, ussd, gammu

How can I establish a session-based M2M connection with gammu? I'm using hardware module SIM800L and a 4G SIM card. I can do USSD and SMS with gammu, but USSD can only be used to communicate with the operator network, not other SIM card, and SMS is costly since even for 10 chars we must pay the price of an SMS. So, I'm looking for a session-based connection where I pay for the traffic.

If gammu does not allow this, is there an alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is some other option than using regular data connection...

Comment: @MichalČihař You mean, regular connection to the Internet with a data plan, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean (if you transfer only few bytes some pay as you go rate might be better fit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gammu does not allow for more than USSD and SMS.

For a GPRS connection, use wvdial.